# Proof of stream reservoir sampling

Tags: algorithm, random, reservoir-sampling

I'm quite familiar with Reservoir Sampling algorithm and I'm thinking what if the total size `N` is given. What benefit can we get under this situation? As a result, here's the algorithm:

```
Let n be the total size of data
Let k be the total size of sample
for each element from data
    if random(0,1) <= k/n
        put this element into sample
        -- k
    -- n
done
```

It looks correct at the first glance but I found it hard to prove. Anybody can help me to prove this algorithm in a formal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a correctness proof for [Dave's fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26235468/2144669). Assume without loss of generality that the stream is `1..n`. We prove inductively that, after `m in {0..n}` iterations through the loop, the sample is distributed as the intersection with `1..m` of a uniform random `k`-combination of `1..n`.

The base case, `m = 0`, is trivial: both the sample and the intersection always are empty. Given the inductive hypothesis for a particular `m`, we now prove it for `m+1`. Let `S` be a random variable representing the set after `m` iterations and let `S'` be a random variable representing the set after `m+1` iterations. Let `&` be set intersection. For all `k`-combinations `T`, we write

```
Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1})
    = Pr(S = T & {1..m}) Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1} | S = T & {1..m}),
```

since `S' = T & {1..m+1}` implies that `S = T & {1..m}`. By the inductive hypothesis and some counting,

```
(n choose k) Pr(S = T & {1..m})
    = ((n - m) choose (k - |T & {1..m}|)).
```

Combining the two equations, we get

```
(n choose k) Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1})
    = ((n - m) choose (k - |T & {1..m}|)) Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1} | S = T & {1..m}).
```

By inspecting Dave's program,

```
Pr(m+1 in S' | S) = (k - |S|) / (n - m).
```

Now there are two cases. The first case is `m+1 in T`.

```
Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1} | S = T & {1..m})
    = Pr(m+1 in S' | S = T & {1..m})
    = (k - |T & {1..m}|) / (n - m)
(n choose k) Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1})
    = ((n - m) choose (k - |T & {1..m}|)) (k - |T & {1..m}|) / (n - m)
    = (n - m - 1) choose (k - |T & {1..m}| - 1)
    = (n - (m+1)) choose (k - |T & {1..m+1}|).
```

The second case is `m+1 not in T`.

```
Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1} | S = T & {1..m})
    = Pr(m+1 not in S' | S = T & {1..m})
    = (n - m - (k - |T & {1..m}|)) / (n - m)
(n choose k) Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1})
    = ((n - m) choose (k - |T & {1..m}|)) (n - m - (k - |T & {1..m}|)) / (n - m)
    = (n - m - 1) choose (k - |T & {1..m}|)
    = (n - (m+1)) choose (k - |T & {1..m+1}|).
```

In both cases, we prove that `Pr(S' = T & {1..m+1})` has the correct value.

Comment: Thanks, that's the exact answer I want!

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly K samples: Let K be the desired sample and k the sample obtained so far. Let N be the total size of the data and n be the set sampled so far. Then check if random(0,1) <= (K-k)/(N-n).

You could also take every (N/K)'th element of the stream, or divide your stream into K substreams and take one element at random from each of them.

Comment: That's the exact algorithm I give above. But how to prove the correctness of this algorithm that each element has the same probability?

Comment: No, it isn't. You're sampling with constant probability.